# Nodejs and Twitter API 1 - res.on function

Tags: node.js, twitter

Newb working through Node.js in 24 Hours.  This challenge comes from Chapter 15 on JSON API's.

The original code:

```
var http = require('http')
    , data = ""
    , tweets = "";

var options = {
    protocol: 'http:'
    , host: 'search.twitter.com'
    , port: 80
    , path: '/search.json?q=%23node.js'
};

var request = http.get(options, function(res) {

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        tweets = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(tweets);
        for (var i= 0; i< tweets.results.length; i++) {
            console.log(tweets.results[i].text)
        }
    });
    res.on('errors', function(e){
        console.log("There was an error: " + e.message)
    });
});
```

My question concerns 'res.on(...)'.  What I think this means is that when the Twitter server responds with a string, 'data', then perform the function.  But I read through the Twitter API (v1 - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1) and didn't see anything that supports that belief.  So how exactly does res.on(...) work? TIA for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res` is a NodeJS event emitter, and `res.on` hooks up a callback for an event. The object `res` that you are using is a Node `http response` object, and it has nothing to do with the REST API that Twitter provides. The Node client makes a request to a http server (be it Twitter or Google or Stackoverflow). When the server responds, the `res` object emits the corresponding events.

You can try

```
, host: 'stackoverflow.com',
, port: 80,
, path: '/questions/18149079/nodejs-and-twitter-api-1-res-on-function'
```

and

```
res.on('end', function() {console.log(data)});
```

and check out the resulting html data :P

Comment: Yes, I'd figured that out.  I'd gone to http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback ... in the example 'xxx.on()' just appears.  So I infer usage is 'res.on([string],callback)' i.e. "when the server responds with the following string, do the following").  If that's correct, how do I know what [string] will be returned e.g. I found nothing in the twitter API that said it would send a string 'data', followed by tweet information in JSON, followed by string 'end'.

Comment: The "string" is the event's name. You have several events, such as "data", "end", "error". The content is in the `chunk` variable. You have the list of events here: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: Ah ... actually it is at http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_class_stream_readable.  Thanks for the guidance!